# Verificar se os dados informados pelo usuário já existem no banco de dados antes de inserir

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jpa

Preciso verificar no banco de dados se as informações que o usuário está tentando inserir já existem, por exemplo:

No cadastro de uma empresa, não posso permitir o mesmo CNPJ para outras. Estou fazendo em JSF 2 com JPA2 Hibernate. Fiz um exemplo de vídeo aula da Algawors, porém lá não mostrava este tratamento.

Comment: No banco, você pode cadastrar o CNPJ como chave primaria.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois está ampla demais a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Vc pode usar seu campo como sendo constraint. Dê uma olhadinha ai. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_constraints.asp

Answer (score 1):

Veja se assim vc consegue fazer!

Dê uma olhada na documentação 
[javax/persistence/Query](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html)

```
String cnpjExiste = "123";
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT sa FROM Empresa AS sa WHERE sa.CNPJ =     ?1", Empresa.class);
query.setParameter(1,  cnpjExiste );
Empresa emp = (Empresa)query.getSingleResult();
if( emp == null ){
  // não existe
 }else{
   // existe
  }


// Ou mais simplificado...

 Empresa empresa = entityManager.find(Empresa.class, 123);
 // empresa == null , não existe
```